# How does a stackoverflow affect a pooled-component in mule?

Tags: java, multithreading, mule

The question pretty much says it all!

I have a mule flow that contains a flow of pooled components if one of the components has a StackOverflowError how does that affect the others threads being executed?

Are the threads assigned a specific stack?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each thread has its own stack.
See [Why reduce the size of the Java JVM thread stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623453/why-reduce-the-size-of-the-java-jvm-thread-stack)